# unexpected end of input in return in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a graph relationship using neo4j

First I have created

```
create (populate_stock_summary:Dag{uuid: "c4ca4238-a0b9-3382-8dcc-509a6f75849b", version: "1760270902"}),
       (map_stock_summary:map{uuid: "d41d8cd9-8f00-3204-a980-0998ecf8427e",version : "1466522157"}),
       (stock_summary_filter :filter{uuid: "6fe5451a-4ed3-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77" ,version : "1460270889"}),
       (rel_00003:relation{uuid: "f33490a0-133d-11e6-a837-0800200c9a66", version : "1466003152"}),
       (stock_summary_datapod:datapod{uuid: "e3fed0a4-4aca-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77", version : "1160270897"}),
       (max_lastSale_formula :formula{uuid: "096dac4b-fee8-11e5-86aa-5e5517507c66",version : "1460270899"}),
       (populate_stock_summary_group:group{uuid: "16fbf5bd-8173-4bff-8b97-1b04e3057475", verssion : "1660270892"}),
       (stock_list:Stock_list_datapod{uuid: "60878178-fee7-11e5-86aa-5e5517507c66", version : "1460270897"})
```

and all nodes are created successfully.

Next I am trying to build a relationship among them. I executed following.

```
Match (populate_stock_summary:Dag),
      (map_stock_summary:Map),
      (stock_summary_filter :filter),
      (populate_stock_summary_group:group),
      (rel_00003:relation),
      (max_lastSale_formula:formula),
      (stock_list:stock_list_datapod),
      (stock_summary_datapod:datapod)
where populate_stock_summary.uuid = "c4ca4238-a0b9-3382-8dcc-509a6f75849b"
  and map_stock_summary.uuid = "d41d8cd9-8f00-3204-a980-0998ecf8427e"
  and stock_summary_filter.uuid ="6fe5451a-4ed3-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77"
  and populate_stock_summary_group.uuid ="16fbf5bd-8173-4bff-8b97-1b04e3057475"
  and rel_00003.uuid = "f33490a0-133d-11e6-a837-0800200c9a66"
  and max_lastSale_formula.uuid = "096dac4b-fee8-11e5-86aa-5e5517507c66"
  and stock_list.uuid ="60878178-fee7-11e5-86aa-5e5517507c66"
  and stock_summary_datapod.uuid ="e3fed0a4-4aca-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77"

create (populate_stock_summary)-[ref1:refers_to{Desc : "Refering_to_map"}]->(map_stock_summary),
       (populate_stock_summary) -[ref2:refers_to{Desc :"Refering_to_filter}] -> (stock_summary_filter),
       (map_stock_summary) -[ref3:source_depends_on]->(rel_00003),

       (map_stock_summary)-[ref4:target_depends_on]->(stock_summary_datapod),

       (map_stock_summary) -[ref5:refers_to]-> (max_lastSale_formula),

       (map_stock_summary) -[ref6:has_groupBy_property] -> (populate_stock_summary_group),

       (populate_stock_summary_group) -[ref7:depends_on] -> (rel_00003),

       (stock_summary_filter) -[ref8:depends_on] -> (rel_00003),

       (rel_00003) - [ref9:depends_on] -> (stock_list)

return ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6,ref7,ref8,ref9
```

And here I am getting

Unexpected end of input: expected '\', ANY or '"' (line 21, column 52 (offset: 1498))
"return ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6,ref7,ref8,ref9

What went wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing quote in the string ***"Refering_to_filter***.